# How do I move a file into another folder/path with golang

Tags: file, csv, go

I know about creating a CSV file or opening a CSV file, but I do not know how to move a CSV file to another path.

Answer (score 1):

To move file `\Folder_A\file.txt` to `\Folder_B\file.txt`, you can use `os` library. Here you have a simple example:

```
 package main

   import (
       "fmt"
       "os"
   )

   func main() {

       err :=  os.Rename("\Folder_A\file.txt", "\Folder_B\file.txt")

       if err != nil {
           fmt.Println(err)
           return
       }
  }
```

In your case, instead of `file.txt`, it will be `YOUR_FILE.csv`. but the idea is the same.

Comment: Is it necessary to specify the destination file name? Is it possible to specify the destination directory alone?

Comment: Also, \ is not the correct path separator outside of Windows; use the `path/filepath` library to build paths in a platform-agnostic way

Answer (score 0):

```
func moveFile(file1, file2 string) error {
   return os.Rename(file1, file2)
}
```

Comment: Doesn't work for moving across filesystems